Python destructors not called in Visual Studio 2017
When I run a python program from VS2017-Pro using the debugger, the destructor is not called automatically when the program exits.  If the python program is executed directly from a command prompt, the destructor is called.
Here's a code snippet:
import MyStuff
thing = MyStuff.thing()
# eof

MyStuff.pyd is a C++ library that contains the constructor, MyStuff::thing() and destructor, MyStuff::~thing().
I can see ~thing() being called when I run this program from the command prompt.  However, when I run it from VisualStudio, the destructor is not called.   If I explicitly call
del thing, the destructor is called in both cases.
Any ideas why this is and if it can be fixed?
One possibility is that VS is holding a reference to thing which prevents the garbage collector from destroying it.
Thanks for your help.

Python does not guarantee that all destructors are called on interpreter exit. If you need code to be called after you are done with a particular object, you should use either a context manager or the atexit module.
